# JSLint was unable to finish. 16.4Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'

Tags: javascript, jslint

Line 16.4, I keep getting this error stating the following: Expected an identifier and instead How do I fix this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "polarArea",
  data: {
    labels: ["HTML", "JQUERY", "JAVASCRIPT", "PYTHON", "CSS", "RUBY", "API"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#adddcf",
        "#3498db",
        "#e8e7e5",
        "#bfb1d5",
        "#f0e0a2",
        "#fed1be",
        "#777777"
      ],
      data: [93, 67, 80, 73, 87, 38, 65],
    }]
  }
});


new Chart(ctx, {
    data: data,
    type: "polarArea",
    options: options
});
```

Comment: Remove the comma.

Comment: I did that on line 15, but it opened up a bunch of new errors on JSLINT. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Other suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483685/jslint-was-unable-to-finish-16-4expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw/47518924#comment81967502_47483685)" are probably limited to "complete JSLinting the file". ;^) First, read up on [JSLint directives](http://jslint.com/help.html#directives) to figure out how to keep some of the stuff that it's complaining about.

It's not that difficult for this file, thankfully.

- If you're using `document`, you have to let JSLint know that it's working in a browser with `browser:true`.
- If you're not following "JSLint accepted" whitespace, you need `white:true` for "messy whitespace".
- You also need to let it know that some things are defined "out of scope", or it'll ask why, in this case, `Chart` is never defined. The `global` directive tells JSLint that `Chart` is defined somewhere else, is in your global scope already, and is fine to use here.
- `data` and `options` in your `new Chart` call have to come from somewhere, so it's going to yell about that, obviously.

In the end, this lints...

```
/*jslint browser:true, white:true */
/*global Chart */

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "polarArea",
  data: {
    labels: ["HTML", "JQUERY", "JAVASCRIPT", "PYTHON", "CSS", "RUBY", "API"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#adddcf",
        "#3498db",
        "#e8e7e5",
        "#bfb1d5",
        "#f0e0a2",
        "#fed1be",
        "#777777"
      ],
      data: [93, 67, 80, 73, 87, 38, 65]
    }]
  }
});


var data = "something";
var options = "something else";

new Chart(ctx, {
    data: data,
    type: "polarArea",
    options: options
});
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much. I have a general idea now to resolve this issue next time. Again, thank you SOOOOO MUCH ruffin! =)

Comment: @KennethChang Great! I'm glad it helped. I'm obviously biased here since it's my answer, but if you'd like to officially [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), that'll ensure folks looking at the [JSLint tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jslint) know this one's taken care of. In any event, happy to introduce you to JSLint directives. JSLint is a much more usable tool after you've got them down.